# Tag cloud and alginment

Tags: css, wordpress

Is their anyway using the code for wordpress tag list to show the active current tag that is selected ie if they select tag 3 should show it in an orange color the code I am using is as follows in a widget.

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud( 'format=list&orderby=count&order=DESC' ); ?>
```

But i not sure on how to do this with css.Also in my blog page the categorys below each post are sitting werid on every post how can i get it to align below Tovább olvasom for every post thanks
The url to check above is 
http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/blog/

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to style the current tag, but you need to add some code in your theme's `functions.php` take a look at this site, helped me when I needed that: http://georgebohnisch.com/extending-the-wordpress-tag-cloud/. Here is the code snipped from that site to protect against link rot:

```
add_filter ( 'wp_tag_cloud', 'tag_cloud_active_class' );

function tag_cloud_active_class( $taglinks ) {
    if ( is_tag() ) {
        $term_id = get_query_var('tag_id');
        $taxonomy = 'post_tag';
        $args ='include=' . $term_id;
        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
        $active_tag = $terms[0]->slug;
    }


    $tags = explode('', $taglinks);
    $regex = "#(.*tag-link[-])(.*)(' title.*)#e";

    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {

        if (strpos($tag,$active_tag)) { 
            $tagn[] = preg_replace($regex, "('$1$2 '.'active-tag'.'$3')", $tag ); 
        } else {
            $tagn[] = preg_replace($regex, "('$1$2$3')", $tag );
        }
    }

    $taglinks = implode('', $tagn);

    return $taglinks;
}
```

To answer your category problem, what exactly is sitting weird?